# Gems not installing for JRuby when selected through chruby due to timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I've been having an issue when trying to install Bundler for either JRuby 9.1.5.0 or the latest 9.1.13.0, when enabled through `chruby` as discussed [here](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/17672-gems-not-installing-due-to-timeout). On the other hand, I'm able to install Bundler for Ruby when selected through `chruby`.

How can I address this?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of RubyGems are you running? Did you try updating it, as was commented in the link?

Comment: thanks for mentioning that. I neglected to mention that I did try to update my rubygems but I get the same timeout error.  When I switch to a non-jruby ruby with chruby, I get a message saying that I'm on the latest version of gem.  The error message I initially get is also as follows for either 9.1.5.0 or 9.1.13.0: `ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>=0), here is why:
Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)` I'm running gem 2.6.13

Comment: Can you access the RubyGems website on your browser? If you can maybe you're problem is that the SSL certification is not being verified correctly, check if you this link helps you: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1758 I don't have experience with `chruby`, but I definitely recommend using RVM, I've had no issues so far.

Comment: yes, I can access the site through the browser and my non-jruby ruby installs can retrieve packages just fine as well.  I'll try installing rvm and see how that compares. I was hoping for a method not involving installing another version manager, but from what I've read, rvm isn't too invasive on my environment and I should be able to just remove the dot folder if it doesn't work for me.